# C++ const int not usable in constant expression

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

I am trying to initialize an array of which I feed the size via an external function.

The external function calculates the size of the vector and outputs them in a pair.

```
// The function has been simplified for the sake of the question
std::pair< int, int> calculate_size ( 
    const double in1,
    const double in2
)
{
    int temp1   = int(in1/in2);
    int temp2   = int(in2/in1);
    std::pair< int, int> output = make_pair(temp1, temp2);
    return output;
}
```

Then, somewhere else, I extract the outputs of the above function to generate the sizes of my array using tie (I am compiling using C++11):

```
// Extract sizes
int tempSize1, tempSize2;
tie(tempSize1, tempSize2) = calculate_size (in1, in2);
const int constSize1 = temp1;  
const int constSize2 = temp2; 

// Initialize vector (compiler error)
std::array<double, constSize1> v1;
std::array<double, constSize2> v2;
```

The compiler gives the following error: `The value of 'constSize1' is not usable in a constant expression`.

However, I can't see what I am doing wrong. According to this [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) website, the example they bring seems to be exactly what I am doing.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:**

A comment suggests `constexpr` is what I need. If I use it without changing the rest, the error message shifts to the `constexpr` line but remains the same in nature:

```
// Modified to use constexpr
int temp1, temp2;
tie(temp1,temp2) = calculate_samples (in1, in2);
constexpr int constSize1 = temp1;
constexpr int constSize2 = temp2;
```

Error: `The value of 'temp1' is not usable in a constant expression`

Comment: `const` is not enough, you need `constexpr` here.

Comment: btw, what's the third argument in `std::array` ?

Comment: Also, `std::array` only has one non-type template parameter.

Comment: very roughly speaking, const means "constant at _runtime_ once initialized to whatever value", constexpr means "a value known by complier at _compile time_". you need the latter as a template parameter of `std::array`. Note also that std::array does not support multidimensional array, as you maybe are trying to get.

Comment: For a `const int` to be usable in a constant expression, it must itself be initialized with a constant expression.

Comment: To clarify: Replacing `const int` with `constexpr int` doesn't help. You need `calculate_size` be a `constexpr` function and feed it `constexpr double`s.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick reaction. I edited my question. I was not misusing array in my code. Originally my issue was with `dlib::matrix`, not `std::array`. I rewrote the code to make my question more generic, as its core problem remained the same. Hence the translation errors. I'll now try the `constexpr` suggestion by @nwp.

Comment: Apparently C++11 doesn't allow variable declarations in `constexpr` functions, but [it basically works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f348971199d6208).

Comment: with your calculate_samples you are converting somehow 2 doubles into 2 int: I doubt that this can result in something known at compile time as you need. Very likely, what you are trying to get is not possible: logically speaking, do you know at compile time the dimension you will need, or you depend to some variable (e.g user input or some db stored value?). In the latter case, you will not be able to use an array

Comment: @GianPaolo, I was thinking that was the problem. Indeed those inputs will depend on a user's request. How would I assign the size of an array-like container given an external input? Thanks

Comment: @raggot Any reason you can't use std::vector?

Comment: `std::vector<double> v1(constSize1);` should do the trick. `constSize1` doesn't need to be `const` or `constexpr`. `std::vector` basically behaves like a dynamic array which seems to be what you actually want.

Comment: @nwp, I actually do have a reason not to use `std::vector`. I do not have enough linear algebra and math support in the standard library for the implementation I needed... But thanks for the suggestion. Btw I just tried to compile the snipped you shared but returning a `constexpr` doesn't seem to be possible. Is there a particular way I should declare it in its `.h` file?

Comment: Did you remove the variable declarations? Clang is ok with C++14 extensions, your compiler might not be. Anyways, according to [this example for `dlib::matrix`](http://dlib.net/matrix_ex.cpp.html) you probably want `dlib::matrix<double> v1(tempSize1, tempSize2);`.

Comment: @raggot, as other are suggesting you will need to revert to a std:vector (or some other container with a runtime variable size. And then, you will possibly don't need at all to calculate the number of elements you need, just add to the vector all elements you want. knowing before the number of element can help you in writing more performant (quicker) code. but do you need this optimization? Note also that in your current `calculate_size` one of the two resulting values will be 0 (if `in2 < in1`, `(int) (in2/in1)` will be always 0

Comment: @nwp. The dynamic construction of `dlib::matrix` was all I needed. I missed that option. Shame on me. A virtual hug and thanks for your time.

Comment: @GianPaolo, thanks. I believe you are right. The solution I ended up with is actually that one. Only, instead of std::vector, I used a different construction of dlib::matrix as suggested by nwp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need `array` (as opposed to `vector`), then marking the function as `constexpr` works perfectly fine.

For working code, see below. Here's the code running on Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/135a906acdb01e08.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

constexpr std::pair<int, int> calculate_size (
    const double in1, const double in2) {
  return std::make_pair(
    static_cast<int>(in1 / in2),
    static_cast<int>(in2 / in1));
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto sizes = calculate_size(4, 2); 

  std::array<double, sizes.first> v1;
  std::array<double, sizes.second> v2;

  std::cout << "[Size] v1: " << v1.size() << " - v2: " << v2.size() << "\n";
}
```

Which prints: `[Size] v1: 2 - v2: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments to the original question by [nwp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484570/nwp) and [GianPaolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3276027/gian-paolo), a possible solution is to avoid using `std::array`, and use a type of container that allows dynamic memory allocation instead, like `std::vector`.